# Prove that is group is abelian

Tags: abelian-groups

Let G be a set of all non-zero real numbers.
And  a * b  = (ab/2).

We need to show (G,*) is an abelian group.

I know I need to show ab = ba, but that seems so trivial,

Assuming the group is abelian,

a * b  = b* a

ab/2 = ba/2
Crossing out 2, we get ab = ba

Is this the correct answer ?

Multiplying both sides inverse of a and b results in 1 = 1 . Am I doing something wrong ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming that the group is abelian is not a good start to a proof that the group is abelian.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to assume the thing you want to prove to be true.

Comment: You're missing the fact that to show something is an Abelian group requires proving that it is a group.

Comment: Then, How should I proceed? The person who taught me this used similar strategy. Can anyone point me in the right direction/

Comment: First attend to group axioms: associativity requires $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$. Then there's identity and inverses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $$a*b=\dfrac{ab}{2}=a\cdot b\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}$$form the other side$$b*a=b\cdot a\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}$$since real numbers with multiplication operator is an Abelian group (If we needed to show that the proof became more complicated) so is this group.